# hoverColumn graphael

Tags: javascript

Estou a utilisar a biblioteca `graphael.js` para criar um gráfico de estatistica. Quero mostrar vários gráficos na mesma página com diferentes valores. O meu problema é no `hoverColumn`, quando passo o rato por cima dos pontos. Para o primeiro gráfico funciona bem, mas para o segunda aparecem valores "`undefined`".

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/aNJxf/17/

Comment: como posso adaptar ao meu código @renan?

Comment: @renan, só deves ter cautela e avisar o usuário sobre as diferenças entre as licenças da biblioteca que usuário utiliza e a do que você sugeriu, pois o [raphael.js utiliza licença MIT](http://raphaeljs.com/license.html), já a biblioteca que você sugeriu utiliza [Creative Commons para versões _Non-commercial_ (Não comercial), sendo que é pago para versões comerciais](http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html).

Comment: @Fernando obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score 0):

Penso ter descoberto o teu problema...
O problema encontra-se nos arrays que estas a passar, não têm o mesmo numero de parametros.

No segundo gráfico tens isto:

```
var xVals2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 8]]; //data coube x1, courbe x2
var yVals2 = [[2, 10, 15, 5], [5, 9, 13, 15, 10 ]]; //data
```

em x tens dois elementos, o primeiro com 7 posições e o segundo com 6 posições, em y tens dois elementos onde o primeiro tem 4 posições e o segundo tem 5 posições...

Tentando simplificar mais... em x o primeiro elemento, deve ter o mesmo numero de posições que o primeiro elemento em y.

Envio-te os arrays do segundo gráfico:

```
var xVals2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7]]; //data coube x1, courbe x2
var yVals2 = [[2, 10, 15, 5], [5, 9, 13, 15, 10 ]]; //data
```